Listening for a file ...Spark streaming!,
I am trying to build an application where I need to read a file. The file will be placed into the directory by another application once or twice a day. I have to create a spark ETL to listen to this  directory, and once the file is received, read it, do some transformations, and load the data into a DB.
How do I implement the listening part of this project? I am confused.
Should I use Spark streaming for this? I was considering it, but it looks like it may be more suited to continuous streaming.

You can try using watchdog for file event handling and PySpark for processing the file without using Spark Streaming.
